# PHP MySQL imagejpeg() not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to save a thumbnail image onto my server using the below code...

```
// Get Variables
$image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$page = $_POST['page'];
$sub_category = $_POST['sub_category'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$paypal = $_POST['paypal'];

// Resize Image
$image_size = getimagesize($image);
$image_width = $image_size[0];
$image_height = $image_size[1]; 

// Resizes image to roughly 150px by 100px
$new_size = ($image_width + $image_height)/($image_width * ($image_height / 65));

$new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
$new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

// Image locations on server
$location_large = "Product Images/Large Images/{$image_name}";
$location_small = "Product Images/Small Images/{$image_name}";

// Create New Image 
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);    

imagecopyresampled($new_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);

imagejpeg($new_image, $location_small, 100);

// Upload original image    
move_uploaded_file($image, "../Product Images/Large Images/{$image_name}");
```

All server permissions are fine! 0777!

Saves original image into 'Large Images' no problems.

Comment: your `move_uploaded_file` path is different from your `$location_large` and `$location_small` paths.

Comment: P.S

The location_large and small variables are just so I can point to the image on-page <img src>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you upload the large image to the parent folder you could do:

```
if (!imagejpeg($new_image, '../' . $location_small, 100))
{
    // Here you make sure this is the function that failed
    die('Imagejpeg failed');
}
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you!

My $location_small path needed '../' to location the correct folder.

Duh! Ha! 

Cheers everyone